# How to use "include" in sequelize from parent table to chlid if there is more than one relation between those two tables

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

**Problem**
we have 2 tables (Project, user) which have 2 relations (assignee, created by)
the problem is at the time of getting data using include, I am not able to distinguish between those 2 relations.

when I use include sequelize it includes the User table through **created by** relation, but what we want is, it should include the User table via **assignee** relation so that we can get all the users to whom the project was assigned.

**Aim is**

To fetch Project details along with all users with details ( id,user_name ) from the User table to whom the given project is assigned

**Scenario** for more details about tables

we have two tables (Project, user) generated by the following code.

For **Project** Table

```
const Project = sequelize.define('project', {
    id: {
    type: DataTypes.BIGINT,
    autoIncrement: true,
    primaryKey: true
  },
    project_title :DataTypes.STRING,
    creator_id :DataTypes.INTEGER
}
```

For **User** Table

```
const User = sequelize.define('user', {
    id: {
    type: DataTypes.BIGINT,
    autoIncrement: true,
    primaryKey: true
  },
    user_name:DataTypes.STRING,
}
```

then we have two relations(assignee, created by) between the above two tables

1. **assignee (Many to many)**-
   One project can be assigned to many users, a user can have many projects. this relation is established via pivot table (UserProject ) by the following code

```
User.belongsToMany(Project, { through: "UserProject" ,foreignKey:"user_id"});
Project.belongsToMany(User, { through: "UserProject" ,foreignKey:"project_id"});
```

2. **created by (one to many)**-
   one user can create many projects, below is the code used to establish the relation

```
User.hasMany(Project, { foreignKey : 'creator_id', sourceKey: 'id' });
Project.belongsTo(models.user, { foreignKey : 'creator_id', targetKey: 'id' });
```

**after insertion Data in tables ** -

```
     User                   Project                                UserProject
id | user_name     id | project_title | creator_id        id  | project_id  | user_id
1  | Lokesh         1 |     HKMS      |     2              1  |      1      |    1   
2  | Rahul                                                 2  |      1      |    3   
3  | Mohit
```

> (project_id of the given project is provided)

My code for getting data

```
const options = { 
      where: { id: project_id },
      include:{
        model: User
      } 
    }
const viewProject = await Project.findAll(options)
console.log(viewProject)
```

***Output***

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "project_title": "HKMS",
            "creator_id": 2,
            "user": {
                "id" : 2,
                "name": "Rahul"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

***Desired Output***

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "project_title": "HKMS",
            "creator_id": 2,
            "users":[
            {
                "id" : 1,
                "name": "Lokesh"
            },
            {
                "id" : 3,
                "name": "Mohit"
            }
          ]
        }
    ]
}
```

> I am new to sequelize please help to solve this riddle

Comment: What is "inclue"?

Comment: its a type mistake it should be include

Answer (score 0):

If you associate two tables with more than one association then you should distinguish them with aliases (the option `as` of a association):

```js
User.belongsToMany(Project, { through: "UserProject" ,foreignKey:"user_id", as: "UsrProjects"});
Project.belongsToMany(User, { through: "UserProject" ,foreignKey:"project_id", as: "PrjUsers"});

User.hasMany(Project, { foreignKey : 'creator_id', as: "CreatedProjects" });
Project.belongsTo(models.user, { foreignKey : 'creator_id', as: "Creator" });
```

Now you can use these aliases in queries like this:

```js
const options = { 
      where: { id: project_id },
      include:[{
        model: User,
        as: "Creator"
      }, {
        model: User,
        as: "PrjUsers"
      }] 
    }
const viewProject = await Project.findAll(options)
console.log(viewProject)
```

And you could see something like this as an output:

```json
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "project_title": "HKMS",
            "creator_id": 2,
            "Creator": {
                "id" : 2,
                "name": "Rahul"
            },
            "PrjUsers":[
            {
                "id" : 1,
                "name": "Lokesh"
            },
            {
                "id" : 3,
                "name": "Mohit"
            }
          ]
        }
    ]
}
```